# Cached windows domain credentials issue

Tags: windows, cache, entra-id

I need to delete or lock out a single cached domain account on a local pc. If I disable the cached logon domain information I will lockout me from the pc if I am not in the office. Is there a way to disable a single cached user? Even by deleting the cache for the single user or locking the login for the user. I hope someone can suggest me something? Or the only way is to be in the office joined to network and the domain, and to disable the logon cache and eventually re-enable it. Best regards!

Comment: Delete the user profile you want to remove.

Comment: I deleted the user folder, but after the reboot I could still login.

Comment: Is there anything to do, to fully remove the user profile (except deleting the folder)?

Comment: Use regedit, HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList, and find the profile of the user you removed the folder, and delete that registry too.

Comment: NExt time when you remove a user use the gui, it remove the folder AND the registry path

Answer (score 2):

Cached credentials are stored in the following location in the registry: HKLM\Security\Cache

There isn't a good or reliable method to manage individual cached credentials.